# How to set JSON payload values to a POJO in Mule

Tags: json, mule

I have the following JSON payload

```
[
    {
        "name": "Car Sale",
        "id": 1,
        "status": "processing"
    },
    {
        "name": "Car Sale",
        "id": 2,
        "status": "processing"
    }
]
```

How can I set the payload values to a Java component

```
public class ClientDetailRequest {
    private String name;
    private Long id;
    private String status;
}
```

I would like to use the POJO as a web service and send the pojo via soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define an inbound endpoint

`<http:http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="8080" path="path/to/service" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json"/>`

2. Get the payload from muleContext and then
   a. Either use mule's inbuilt object-to-json-transformer to covert JSON to POJO

`<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="xxxx.xxxx.ClientDetailRequest"/>`

b. Or user custom transformer (only if above option does not work)

---

Oh just realized that you want to handle array on objects. In this case you you should get json and transform it to a Map.
`<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />`

And then query it using MEL like standard MVEL or Java syntax
`<logger message="#[payload.ClientDetailRequest[0]]" level="INFO" />`

Now various ways to handle this - Do look at MVL expressions or groovy or use plain Java code..

Answer (score 0):

To transform your json to a java object you can use:

```
<flow name="stack" doc:name="stack">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="jsonArray" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="in flow."/>
<json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="mule.example.ClientDetailRequest[]"/>
<collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
<logger message="payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I hope to help;